# Adding a script to Angular works only in index.html

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 17 and I am trying to use a script to generate a form in a component, this is the source for the script: [https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/inchtml/ajaxPayment/ajax.js?token={TOKEN}](https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/inchtml/ajaxPayment/ajax.js?token=%7BTOKEN%7D), TOKEN is a token of a transaction that I should receive from backend only when accessing payment tab. Of course angular doesnt let you create a script just by using <script></script> tags, because it will be removed. The only way that I managed to make it work was when putting it inside index.html (token was added by hand, not API). But when doing so I can't use API call.

I have tried creating script:

```
const s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = 'https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/inchtml/ajaxPayment/ajax.js?token={REAL_TOKEN_FROM_API}'
```

And then appending it using:

- Renderer2 and appending it to the body, header or component
- Basic appending: document.body/head.appendChild(s)

I don't get any errors about DomSanitizer or anything, the script is generated, it can be inspected but it doesn't connect to the component when used outside index.html.

Component that should have script generated inside:

```
<div
    id="P24FormContainer"
    data-sign="{P24SIGN}"
    data-successCallback="{FinishPaymentFunction}"
    data-failureCallback="{PaymentErrorFunction}"
    data-dictionary='{DICTIONARY JSON}'
></div>
```

Has any of you made something similar or maby even using this API, because I have no idea what to do next, it seems that I have tried everything and nothing works.

Documentation link for more context: https://developers.przelewy24.pl/#tag/Card-Description/How-to-make-in-shop-card-payment

I know that the transaction can be processed on providers side, but I have to do it on my side.

Renderer2, Basic appending to head or body

Comment: can you include the component template and code which adds the script, also, you could inspect the script, see what it does, does it use querySelector to find the container, or it loads other scripts etc., to give more context, because it's not clear why it wouldn't work, if added via component..

Comment: @traynor
I am using:
`document.head.appendChild(s)`
or
`document.body.appendChild(s)`
or
`@ViewChild('test1') test1: ElementRef | undefined;`
`this.test1?.nativeElement.appendChild(s);`
`this.renderer.appendChild(this.test1?.nativeElement, s);`

#test1 is added to component.
and the generation is started using a button

Comment: well, that doesn't help much, but it seems that script is added, but not working for some reason.. try inspecting what the returned script does.., try maybe adding `s.onload`, also, try maybe get the url with http, as in `this.http.get('scripturl').subscribe(data =>..` and try  appending content to script tag and then adding the script tag to head, but that's just guessing and maybe pointless..

Comment: for example, inspect if the returned script maybe runs when DOM is loaded etc., so you'd need to trigger it manually somehow..

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do it using iframe:

```
frameSrcdoc = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta
                name="viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
            >

            <script src="https://sandbox.przelewy24.pl/inchtml/ajaxPayment/ajax.js?token={TOKEN}"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div
                id="P24FormContainer"
                data-sign="{P24SIGN}"
                data-successCallback="successCallback"
                data-failureCallback="failureCallback"
                data-dictionary='{DICTIONARY JSON}'
            ></div>

            <script>
                function successCallback(event) {
                    sendMessage("SUCCESS");
                }
    
                function failureCallback(event) {
                    sendMessage("FAILURE");
                }

                function sendMessage(message) {
                    window.parent.postMessage(message, '*');
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>`
```

ngOnInit:

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.srcdoc = this.frameSrcdoc;
this.renderer.appendChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, iframe);
window.addEventListener('message', (result) => this.receiveMessage(result), false);
```